# 301 Redirect in asp.net

Tags: .net, asp.net, http-status-code-301

I have just uploaded a new website [www.tapasya.co.in](http://www.tapasya.co.in). When I tried to access, it showing me a blank page.
But when I tried using the complete path of the home page http://www.tapasya.co.in/Web%20Pages/Home.aspx , its working.

**I think, I have figured the problem, which might be occuring**. I have to put this page at the root folder, to access it using www.tapasya.co.in. But I don't want to put this page at the root folder.
I searched it on google, and some solutions says, that I have to do a **301 redirect**.

But I dont know how to do that.
Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this is meant by 301 redirect :

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
    Response.AddHeader("Location","http://www.aspcode.net/newpage");
}
```

More info [here](http://www.aspcode.net/ASPNET-301-redirect.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you really want your Pages to be located in "Web Pages" then add this Default.aspx in your root folder:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">
    void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Web Pages/Home.aspx");
    }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <a href="Web Pages/Home.aspx">Redirect</a>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Sorry, my fault! My Code gives a 302, temp. Redirect. Thomas Code is a 301.

Comment: @Arthur: No issues, atleast I got to know that this is called a 302 Redirect.